# Merging mesh parts that use the same texture and shader

Tags: texturing

I have created a model and imported it into Blender.

[image]

All parts of the mesh use one and the same texture image.

However, when load my blend file in Unity, each and every mesh part receives an individual shader / material slot:

[image]

My problem is

1) that I have to re-assign the material in Unity (well, I guess, I will sooner or later find out why Unity does not use the correct material right away)

2) that I would like to merge some parts into a single part (for example, "Face", "Legs", "Arms", etc. should be a single object called "Body" since they will use the same shader)

Can somebody tell me how I can do that?

Thank you!

Comment: If you select one part in Blender then double tap the 'a' key it will select everything. If you press 'Ctrl+j' it will merge all the parts.  Unity should now only see one mesh, material and texture.

Comment: Thank you! Do you want to make your comment the reply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select one part in Blender then double tap the 'a' key, it will select everything.

If you press 'Ctrl+j' it will merge all the parts.

Unity should now only see one mesh, material and texture.